# how to group levels into a subgroup in a ggplot forest plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-forestplot

```
> dput(fig2b_data)
structure(list(subgroup = c("sex", "sex", "ai_comorbid_bool", 
"ai_comorbid_bool", "non_ai_comorbid_bool", "non_ai_comorbid_bool", 
"age_70_plus", "age_70_plus", "ecog_combined", "ecog_combined", 
"indication_combined", "indication_combined", "site", "site", 
"site", "site", "site", "site", "site", "site"), level = c("Female", 
"Male", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "0", "1+", "Adjuvant", 
"Metastatic / Unresectable", "Cambridge", "Belfast", "Cardiff", 
"Liverpool", "Norwich", "Preston", "Southampton", "Taunton"), 
    subgroup_level = c("sex_Female", "sex_Male", "ai_comorbid_bool_No", 
    "ai_comorbid_bool_Yes", "non_ai_comorbid_bool_No", "non_ai_comorbid_bool_Yes", 
    "age_70_plus_No", "age_70_plus_Yes", "ecog_combined_0", "ecog_combined_1+", 
    "indication_combined_Adjuvant", "indication_combined_Metastatic / Unresectable", 
    "site_Cambridge", "site_Belfast", "site_Cardiff", "site_Liverpool", 
    "site_Norwich", "site_Preston", "site_Southampton", "site_Taunton"
    ), ref = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), adj_or = c(1, 1.92697788983048, 1, 
    0.309313271153888, 1, 1.60176654927755, 1, 0.581067651194834, 
    1, 0.606677244239784, 1, 0.757510322046024, 1, 0.0671548910659019, 
    1.24115412701041, 0.111740502056371, 0.296334401152569, 0.407313416513578, 
    0.100703132319318, 0.0580853387590806), ci_low = c(NA, 1.08574689964253, 
    NA, 0.0933004210866726, NA, 0.813446935851162, NA, 0.300096568750007, 
    NA, 0.301300997438692, NA, 0.395638695943013, NA, 0.0184879397812241, 
    0.316512222510664, 0.0310182213975059, 0.0774035454553755, 
    0.0834303368267395, 0.0228743220824828, 0.011193138928203
    ), ci_high = c(NA, 3.4667621174982, NA, 0.929482385449043, 
    NA, 3.1938659749789, NA, 1.11325241104074, NA, 1.21374279615277, 
    NA, 1.44670881667103, NA, 0.205952672316014, 4.59055508109202, 
    0.342443550375257, 1.00710088916867, 2.04034216674928, 0.387728614421501, 
    0.257636420370032), p = c(NA, 0.0263295963311719, NA, 0.0432646112707497, 
    NA, 0.175314541854903, NA, 0.103298047943536, NA, 0.158264479732785, 
    NA, 0.399589361570504, NA, 8.78601713425597e-06, 0.747238599523183, 
    0.000291277241946869, 0.0597081504970594, 0.260985385401162, 
    0.00132018341690714, 0.000328378914869459), sig = c(NA, TRUE, 
    NA, TRUE, NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, NA, 
    TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), col = c("REF", 
    "UP", "REF", "DOWN", "REF", "INSIG", "REF", "INSIG", "REF", 
    "INSIG", "REF", "INSIG", "REF", "DOWN", "INSIG", "DOWN", 
    "INSIG", "INSIG", "DOWN", "DOWN")), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I'd like to draw a forest plot, but where each level is grouped by subgroup. How can I do this?

I've tried this so far to get my plot, but struggling with grouping the levels:

........................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
# plot
ggplot(data = fig2b_data, aes(x = adj_or, y = subgroup_level)) + 
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = ci_high, xmin = ci_low, color = col), size = .5, height = .2) +
  geom_point(aes(color = col), size = 2) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image: forest plot]

I would like:

```
_________________________
Sex
Male (ref)                        x
Female          |----x-----| 
_______________________________________________________________
AI comorbid
No (ref)                          x
Yes          |----x-----| 
_______________________________________________________________
Site
Cambridge(ref)                    x
Preston          |----x-----| 
Southampton                     |----x-----| 
Belfast                                        |----x-----|

__________________________________1____________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help. First you have to use melt function to arrange your data based on the target columns you want and then you can plot.  Even though, since I dont know what do you want to do, my plot has many points for the `subgroup = site` and I think this doesn't convey any graphical information.

```
df <- melt(df,id.vars=c("subgroup",'adj_or','ci_low','ci_high','col'))


ggplot(df, aes(x=adj_or, y=subgroup, color=variable))+
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = ci_high, xmin = ci_low, color = col), size = .5,height = .2) +
  geom_point(aes(color = col), size = 2) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: apologies I wanted only one point with error bars per line. I just wanted to show the levels associated with each subgroup with slight separations. I've amended my question to clarify.